# Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Он же сам, ребёнком, пережил то военное время.

Свою первую квартиру он получил в семидесятом году, в 38 лет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом предложении запятые возможны, если трактовать "ребенком", как неполную конструкцию от "когда был ребенком" или "будучи ребенком". Однако можно и не ставить запятые, видя в этом слове обычное обстоятельство времени - когда? ребенком, в детстве.
  Во втором предложении явное уточняющее обстоятельство времени, запятая нужна

Comment: Спасибо большое.